# How to compare 2 instance of a class such that they are equal if at-most there Id differ?

Tags: c#, object

I want to compare all the field of 2 instances except their ID (two similar object can have different Id but all other fields should be same). Is there some direct way to do it in C#

Comment: Override `.Equals()`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He should be implementing IComparer and comparing the objects, not overriding equals.

Comment: @Dispersia That's also a good point. Which way to go depends strongly on the use case. It seems the id-oblivious comparison could define the general equality relation for the class. In this case, overriding `.Equals()` is the way to go. If it is not, then it is a custom comparer.